# How to run framework 7 Android Material for PhoneGap?

Tags: phonegap-build, html-framework-7, phonegap-desktop-app

I downloaded Framework 7 1.5.2 for Phonegap because the latter's built in template is for iOS. And what I need is for Android. However, when I open index.html it shows two phones but no effect.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1ASU.jpg

Here's what it looks like when I click on the kitchen sink for search bar:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgbdZ.jpg

How do I view it with the Materials Design?

Kindly just open the images in another tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this step to make it work:

- First, open your framework7 folder after you downloaded it.
- Rename folder "dist" to "build"
- Open file "index.html" with notepad or other code editor
- Scrolldown to body and add "index.html" to all links. Example : `<iframe src="./kitchen-sink-ios/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>` become `<iframe src="./kitchen-sink-ios/index.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>`
- Save and run.

Comment: Follow up question, where do I find the list in the Virtual List. I searched the .js and it isn't that one. I want to make my own list to create a sort of pricelist.